# Position Window before created using shell hook

Tags: c#, shell, winapi

I have a c# application that is launching applications. I am setting a Shell Hook to catch when the actual windows are created, `ShellEvents.HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED`.

I would like to position the windows **BEFORE** they appear onscreen. Is there a combination of ShellHook events to accomplish this. I notice I am getting a `HSHELL_REDRAW` just before `HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED` with a valid handle -- is that where I can do the positioning? Or do I need a different hook.

I am wondering if there is a way to hook the create parms for the window, to set this positioning at a lower level.